# Static Table View cell seque to ViewController clicking in Cell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

When I create a table view with static cells, and connect cell with other ViewController in storyboard and run this, It is seque when clicked in disclosure indicator, but when click in cell it`s nothink. How can I seque it with click on the cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Control drag your cell to the other view controller and click the first modal. Not the one under accessory action.

Comment: Check if this answer works. If it doesn't, maybe check if selection is enabled for your table view. Failing that, you may also check if any gesture recognizers have been added. In my experience depending on where you add it, it may interfere with tableview selections.